# How to connect a device to a Rails server via TCP?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tcp, ruby-on-rails-5

let me explain what I've already completed and what is needed to be done.

### What's I've done

Rails server with PG database that returns some data to a user from DB via GET request.

### What's needs to be completed

I need to connect the device to this server via TCP. The manufacturer of the device asks me to provide the server address and the port, so he can configure the device to send some messages to the port provided. This messages should be recorded to DB (this part is not important, just to let you know the flow I'm trying to achieve) and then a user can get those messages by GET request mentioned above.

### The question

How to set up the Rails server to accept TCP messages from the device to a specified port? How to handle those messages? E.g. the simplest: how to print the message received?

Is it even possible with Rails? If you have a better option on how to achieve the flow mentioned above, please share it.

I'd appreciate some help with code or links.

Comment: Is you device sending a standard GET HTTP request? You can run a web server on any port with `rails s -p 12345`. This will give you a server talking on port 12345.

Comment: @Beartech the device communicates via TCP, not HTTP

Comment: [TCPSocket](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/socket/rdoc/TCPSocket.html) probably does what you want, but without knowing more about how the device communicates via TCP I can't tell you much more. TCPSocket is pure Ruby -- not Rails -- and how you would implement something like this in your Rails stack again depends in large part on the specific implementation you want to have. Personally, I would spin something like this out into a microservice because Rails is an MVC framework behind an HTTP server, and your desired design is explicitly not that.

Comment: @anothermh I managed to make it work using TCPServer and running it as a rake task. However I'm not sure it's a good solution, coz I'm not quite familiar with Ruby/Rails, etc

Answer (score 0):

Just start your rails server with command `rails s -b 0.0.0.0`

this will bind your public IP with your server so that you can connect with other devices to your rails server.

for example your IP is `192.168.64.40` so, after this command you can do like `192.168.64.40:3000` in to other device's browser so that they can connect to your rails server